# Programmatically Cycle through Tab-Order in QT5

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a QT5 application in which I have to simulate a tab keypress on an external event i.e. I need to cycle through the taborder list and setFocus on the next element.

I cannot find any method to get the tab-order list programmatically. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setTabOrder

Comment: I would set the tab order myself keeping that information somewhere. However, if you need to set focus on widgets in specific order why don't you just do it?

Comment: @eyllanesc - Your link is about setting the tab order, I need a way to retrieve it.

Comment: @vahancho - The tab order is set at design time in qtcreator by a different user. And I need to setFocus on widgets in that specific order only at runtime.

Comment: @Bhavin Well it is not possible, that is managed by the private API, the best option is the one indicated by vanancho

Comment: @Bhavin, I think if there is no such API, you probably don't need it at all. Just set focus on any widget and send key event (Tab) to jump to the next widget. With this you will follow the order set at design time.

Comment: @vahancho: Can you please elaborate a bit more on how to do that, especially "send key event (Tab)" part. An example or code snippet would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @Bhavin, please refer to `QCoreApplication::sendEvent()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a combination of `QWidget::` [nextInFocusChain()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nextInFocusChain) / [previousInFocusChain()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#previousInFocusChain) and [setFocus()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus) method or [setFocus()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus-1) slot?  (There are some other ways to set focus as well, all cross-linked in the Qt docs.)

`nextInFocusChain()`and `previousInFocusChain()` [provide public API access](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp.html#6842) to the underlying private members which seem to control the tabbing order. You can see them being used in [QWidget::setTabOrder()](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp.html#6950) for example.

Current focus widget could be found with either [QWidget::focusWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusWidget) of the parent widget, or [QApplication::focusWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusWidget). Note that `QWidget::focusWidget()` will also return the first widget in the focus order if none currently have focus. This starting point could be used to build a list of widgets in tab order.